# How to modify GREP output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have a script which uses grep to output like this:

```
12 Apples
10 Grapes
11 Mangoes
```

I want to the output as

```
Apples: 12 Grapes: 10 Mangoes: 11
```

How to modify the grep output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pipe to awk like:

```
$ echo "
12 Apples
10 Grapes
11 Mangoes
" | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=": "; ORS=" "; } NF >= 2 { print $2, $1; }'
Apples: 12 Grapes: 10 Mangoes: 11
```

replacing, of course, the echo cmd with the `grep` you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `awk`:

```
$ grep regex file | awk '{ printf "%s: %d ", $2, $1 }; END { printf "\n" }'
Apples: 12 Grapes: 10 Mangoes: 11
```

This would use `printf` to print out your lines to the specified format, and then add a newline at the end, since that's what you probably want. If you're not familiar with `awk`, `$1` and `$2` represent **positional parameters**, which is to say, the first (in this case, space-separated) field, and the second.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to have no spaces around the colon in the output you can simply do:

```
$ grep ... | tr ' \012' ': '; echo
```

This just changes the spaces to colons and the newlines to spaces.  The echo is there to give a trailing newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed:

```
grep … | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\) \(.*\)$/\2: \1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ghc`:

```
$> cat ./text 
12 Apples
10 Grapes
11 Mangoes

$> cat ./text  | ghc -e "getContents >>= putStrLn . concatMap ((\(num,name) -> (drop 1 name) ++ \": \" ++ num ++ \" \") . break (== ' ')) . lines"
Apples: 12 Grapes: 10 Mangoes: 11
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e "12 Apples\n10 Grapes\n11 Mangoes" |
sed ':a;$!{N;ba};s/\(\S*\) \(\S*\)\n*/\2: \1 /g'
Apples: 12 Grapes: 10 Mangoes: 11
```